# How to use `seaborn` to distplot an array of double value in Python3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I tried to use `distplot` to plot an array of double value but failed. Below is my source code:

```
>>> import seaborn as sns, numpy as np
>>> sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
>>> x = np.random.randn(100)
>>> ax = sns.distplot(x)
```

Below is the error I got. I don't know what wrong with my code. Does anyone know the issue?

```
>>> ax = sns.distplot(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 221, in distplot
    kdeplot(a, vertical=vertical, ax=ax, color=kde_color, **kde_kws)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 604, in kdeplot
    cumulative=cumulative, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 270, in _univariate_
kdeplot
    cumulative=cumulative)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py", line 328, in _statsmodels
_univariate_kde
    kde.fit(kernel, bw, fft, gridsize=gridsize, cut=cut, clip=clip)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.py", line 146, in fit
    clip=clip, cut=cut)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/kde.py", line 506, in kden
sityfft
    f = revrt(zstar)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/kdetools.py", line 20, in
revrt
    y = X[:m/2+1] + np.r_[0,X[m/2+1:],0]*1j
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

BTW, I am using python3.6.

Comment: Running it on Python 2.7 works fine; cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: I am using Python3.6. Is this because of the version different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by an old version of `statsmodels` and the problem is fixed in version 0.8.0. Upgrade it as described in https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1092

```
conda update statsmodels
```